# Meaning of crackling a fire?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-choice

"I think he has done it [cranked up the air-conditioning] so he can crackle a fire and force us together under the blankets".

What does the author mean with *crackle a fire*? Or more specifically, what's the meaning of *crackle* in this context?

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. Please [edit] your post to include the context: is this written or spoken, and what is the larger narrative or conversation here?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the Gone Girl, the same as your previous question.  Can you confirm the source and provide a bit more context. It's not a standard idiom, so it must be something that the author made up.  That means you need a bit more context to figure it out.

Comment: The author is using the verb "crackle" creatively. The sound of fires is often described as "crackling" and the author is using the verb "crackle" to suggest that a cozy, crackling fire will encourage the couple to snuggle under a blanket. This is not a standard meaning of the verb "crackle."

Comment: Thank you, @SarahT, for explaining this uncommon but witty use of the verb "crackle".

Comment: I am impressed by your memory, @JamesK - and yes, the source you stated is correct. I wouldn't like to trouble you with the complicated context of the book, especially considering the number of good answers to this question that already exists in the comment section, but thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've looked up "crackle" in the dictionary you'll know it can be a *verb* (the action of making a crackling noise, which the fire itself would do) or a *noun* (the name of the sound the fire makes). A person *could* 'crackle' if they themselves made a crackling sound, but it is uncommon to say that a person *crackled* a fire, and I can see why you think it might be incorrect.

This is an example of *anthimeria* - creatively using a noun as a verb. This actually happens quite a lot, and sometimes leads to words becoming accepted into the dictionary as verbs. For example, 'knifed', meaning to stab someone with a knife.

In your quotation, the idea conveyed is that the person has made a crackling fire. A lot of people enjoy sitting by an open fire, and find the sound of a crackling fire has a warming effect on them, making them feel cosy and snug. I believe the implication is that the person referred to is trying to create this kind of atmosphere.